# How do I render a Django object (form) from Javascript?

Tags: javascript, django

I have loaded Django form elements to localStorage for persistence of changes using localStorage.setItem("Key", JSON.stringify(obj)). That seems to be working. Now I want to retrieve the object and render it into my HTML page from Javascript. My script looks like this:

```
// This script retrieves the Django form object that was stored as a JSON

// from localStorage, parses it and posts it on the html page

// Get label from document

var myLabel = document.getElementById("currLabelID"  + 
id_suffix).value.replace(/ /g,"");

//alert("CurrLabel = " + myLabel);

// Retrieve the form object from localStorage

var yummy = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(myLabel));

// Put form object into page

//var myDiv = document.getElementByName("theFieldPostDiv");

//$( myDiv ).append( yummy );

//var form = document.createElement('form');

//form.appendChild(yummy);

//document.write( yummy );

//{{ yummy }}


//$(document).ready(function() {
//
//        $( "theFieldPostDiv" ).append( yummy );
//
//});

//$( "theFieldPostDiv" ).append( $(yummy) );

//document.body.appendChild(yummy);

//$.append(yummy);

//yummy.post();

$(function() {
    $(".theFieldPostDiv").hide();
    $("#form-group").submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var posting = $.post(".theFieldPostDiv", yummy);
        posting.done(function(data) {
            $(".theFieldPostDiv").show();
        });
        posting.fail(function(data) {
            alert("Fail")
        });
    });
});
```

Note: The "theFieldPostDiv" is where I want to render the form object in the page.

The commented code shows several ways I attempted to accomplish this. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So the solution I found was, at the bottom of the template add this:

```
{% block js %}

function loadInputLocalStorage(){
    $('#input-form :input').each(function(){
        var key = $(this).attr('id');
        if(localStorage.getItem(key)) {
            var value = localStorage.getItem(key);
            $(this).val(value);
        }
    });
}
loadInputLocalStorage();

function saveInputLocalStorage() {
    $('#input-form :input').each(function(){
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        var value = $(this).val();
        localStorage.setItem(id, value);

    });
}

$('#input-form').change(function() {
    saveInputLocalStorage();
});


{% endblock %}
```

In the body of the template I have this:

```
          {% for boundfield in elements %}

              <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="control-label col-sm-5" style="text-align:right;"
                         for="{{boundfield.id_for_label}}">{{ boundfield.label }}
                  </label>
                  <div class="col-sm-7" id="{{boundfield.id_for_label}}"
                       aria-describedby="{{boundfield.id_for_label}} | addstr:ex">{{ boundfield }}
                  </div>
              </div>

              {% if boundfield.help_text %}
                  <p class="col-sm-offset-5 col-sm-7"> <small style="color: grey">{{ boundfield.help_text|safe }}</small></p>
              {% endif %}

              {% for error in boundfield.errors %}
                  <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10"><span class="text-danger small">{{ error }}</span></div>
              {% endfor %}

          {% endfor %}
```

where 'elements' is passed in from the view.

Note: I didn't figure this out by myself, I had tremendous assistance from Beheen. Hope this helps the next guy...